# Select the sum of a column and value of the last column together in a SQL query

Tags: mysql

I have a table named results where I have id(pk) and marks. I want to develop a select query to get the sum(marks) and also the highest individual marks in a single query. Is it possible?

sample data:

- id ---- marks
- 1 ---- 50
- 2 ---- 60
- 3 ---- 70
- 4 ---- 44

Expected output: Sum(224), last_marks(44)

I have tried the following way:

```
SELECT SUM(marks), latest.marks
FROM results
JOIN ( SELECT marks FROM results ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1) as latest;
```

It shows error as follows:
Error Code: 1052. Column 'marks' in field list is ambiguous

Comment: Please add sample data to your question.

Comment: It seems like these _should_ be two separate queries instead of one. Why do you need them in one query?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen added.

Comment: @HunterMcMillen I need to pass the values in front-end as this format.

Comment: @mnur that is unrelated to the number of queries that you execute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get result using seperate queries and merging results using `UNION`.

```
SELECT SUM(marks) AS marks_sum FROM results
UNION
SELECT marks AS latest_marks  FROM results WHERE id=(SELECT MAX(id) FROM results)
```

OR if need results in one row use query in query:

```
SELECT (SELECT SUM(marks) FROM results) AS marks_sum,
(SELECT marks FROM results WHERE id=(SELECT MAX(id) FROM results)) AS latest_marks
```

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I was looking for the 2nd solution!